# Customizing X-axis label for groups of 7 (weeks)

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a set of data organized as a list where each list entry represents a day of the week.  The data starts on a Sunday.  It represents about 5 months of data.  Each element of the list is {date,value} where date is a full calendar date.  Thus, the data looks like {{date,value},{date,value},...}.

I have been successful with the DateListPlot function but I want the labeling of the X-Axis to show groups of 7 data points labeled as "Week 1", "Week 2", and so forth.  I would like a single tic-mark between the weekly groups of 7.

I am very new to Mathematica graphics functions and I must admit that finding out and learning how to do this from the documentation is not easy.

Comment: to let you know, having made a 2nd Update with improvements and tidy up.  Likely, speed is not an issue for a 5 months data set. However it may be interesting to know that using `DayRange` is about 100 times faster than using `Select` or `Pick` in combination with `DateRange` . Enjoy "playing" with Mathematica, as you mention in your profile....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
wd = WeatherData["SanDiego", "Temperature", {"Jan. 1, 2014", "Aug. 1, 2014", "Day"}];

(*   for version 10+ evaluate:  wd = wd // Normal // QuantityMagnitude;   *)

sundays = Pick[wd[[All, 1]], DayName /@ wd[[All, 1]], Sunday];
wednesdays = Pick[wd[[All, 1]], DayName /@ wd[[All, 1]], Wednesday];
```

`Ticks` at Wednesday noon:

```
ticks = MapIndexed[{AbsoluteTime[#] + 60 60 12, 
     Rotate["Week " <> ToString[First@#2], Pi/2]} &, wednesdays];

DateListPlot[wd, BaseStyle -> Thick, AspectRatio -> 1/4,
 FrameTicks -> {ticks, Automatic, None, None}, 
 GridLines -> {sundays, None}, ImageSize -> 900, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

**Update:**

You can also use `DayMatchQ` instead of `DayName[#]==...`:

```
Pick[wd[[All, 1]], DayMatchQ[#, Wednesday] & /@ wd[[All, 1]]] == wednesdays
(* True *)
```

Use different colors for different weeks:

```
wd = WeatherData["Kirkland", "Temperature", {"Jan. 1, 2014", "Aug. 1, 2014", "Day"}];
wd2 = wd /. {x_, y_} /; DayMatchQ[x, Sunday] :> Sequence[{x, y}, {x, y}];
wd2b = Split[wd2, ! (DayMatchQ[#[[1]], Sunday] && DayMatchQ[#2[[1]], Sunday]) &];
DateListPlot[wd2b, BaseStyle -> Thick, AspectRatio -> 1/4, 
 FrameTicks -> {ticks, Automatic, None, None}, GridLines -> {sundays, None},
 ImageSize -> 900, Joined -> True, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** If there are gaps in the data so that some `Sunday`s and/or `Wednesday`s are skipped as in the example provided by @penguin77 in the comments, then you can use

```
dr = DateRange[wd[[1, 1]], wd[[-1, 1]]];
wednesdays = Pick[dr, DayMatchQ[#, Wednesday] & /@ dr];
sundays = Pick[dr, DayMatchQ[#, Sunday] & /@ dr];
```

Stealing and modifying @penguin77's great find we get a much cleaner way to get the dates we need for ticks and grid lines:

```
{wednesdays, sundays} = DayRange[## & @@ wd[[{1, -1}, 1]], #]&/@ {Wednesday, Sunday}
```

Splitting the data into separate weeks would be more involved in this case.

Comment: Are you using 10.1?  In 10.0.2 this throws errors. `wd[[All, 1]]` is not valid.

Comment: @MrWizard, i am using version 9.0.1.0 (windows 8 64bit).

Comment: It looks like we have an incompatible change.  Do you have time to Chat?

Comment: @kguler when trying wd = WeatherData["WMO89009", 
   "Temperature", {"Jun. 1, 2014", "Dec. 1, 2014", "Day"}]; proposed solution seems not to work (see missing grid line between week 6 and 7 and gap in week 8).   It looks like that ticks and GridLines are dependent on data being systematically available for Sundays and Wednesday. Or am I missing  something ?

Comment: @penguin77, you are right; I assumed there are no gaps in the data. If there are gaps ticks and gridlines can be off, so can the splitting into weeks. A more robust way would be to use `DateRange` of the data to identify Wednesday and Sunday dates:, e.g.,  `wednesdays = 
  Pick[DateRange[wd[[1, 1]], wd[[-1, 1]]], 
   DayName /@ DateRange[wd[[1, 1]], wd[[-1, 1]]], Wednesday];
sundays =   Pick[DateRange[wd[[1, 1]], wd[[-1, 1]]], 
   DayName /@ DateRange[wd[[1, 1]], wd[[-1, 1]]], Sunday];`

Comment: @kguler, yes indeed, this is looks more straightforward than `NestList` and `DatePlus`, that I have proposed and leads to  `Select[DateRange[dset[[1, 1]], dset[[-1, 1]]] , 
    DayMatchQ[#, Wednesday] &]`   (being shorter)

Comment: @penguin77,  it is not a requirement in this q/a,  but  `Pick` is usually faster than `Select`. Also, in this case, you save a single character using `Select[DateRange@@wd[[;;,1]][[{1,-1}]],DayName@#==Wednesday&]`  versus `Pick[#,DayName/@#,Wednesday]&[DateRange@@wd[[;;,1]][[{1,-1}]]]` :)

Comment: @kguler your `Pick` looks now nice and elegant. `Pick` is usually faster than `Select`, however requires a `Map` in this case. Evaluating this example with a data set of a 10 years period `Pick` still wins over `Select` in a "head-to-head" race being 0.3443 percent faster. So you are right! :). thx for insights

Comment: @kguler,  I know, it's not a requirement of q/a. Anyhow `DayRange[First@First@#, First@Last@#, Wednesday]&[wd]` is about 100 times faster.....told me the penguins....:)

Comment: @penguin77, much neater too. I am glad penguins persevere; i learned something really cool. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

Creating a data set `dset` with date values for the period of 5 months starting on a Sunday associated with random integers ( `DayName @ {2015, 04, 12} (* Sunday*)`).

```
dset = DateRange[{2015, 04, 12}, 
     DatePlus[{2015, 04, 12}, {5, "Month"}], 
     Quantity[1, "Days"]] // {#, RandomInteger[100, Length @  #]} &  //
    Transpose ;
```

To create tick marks, FoldList gets all Wednesdays (Sunday + 4) from the dset by using DatePlus which is then associated with tick labels in the postfix expressions.

```
ticks = FoldList[DatePlus[#, {1, "Week"}] &, DatePlus[dset[[1, 1]], {4, "Day"}], 
 dset[[All, 1]]] // {#, 
  Rotate["Week " <> ToString @#, \[Pi]/2] & /@ 
   Range @ Length@# } &   // Transpose;
```

The grid corresponds to the starting of a week. E.g. Week 1 starts on the first Sunday. Therefore the value associated with Sunday lays on the first line and 6 points lay in between.

```
grid = FoldList[DatePlus[#, {1, "Week"}] &, dset[[1, 1]], 
  dset[[All, 1]]];
```

And here the plot

```
DateListPlot[dset, Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {DatePlus[dset[[1, 1]], {-1, "Week"}], 0}, 
 GridLines -> {grid, None}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 800, 
 Frame -> False]
```

[image]

**Update 1**

To demonstrate that above solution works as well if there are gaps of data points, because the ticks and grid lines do not depend on availability of data points.

Here a data set from Amundsen-Scott 90°00’S with temperature measurements in irregular intervals.

```
dset = WeatherData["WMO89009", 
   "Temperature", {"Jun. 1, 2014", "Dec. 1, 2014", "Day"}];
```

Here a more robust way to generate ticks and grid lines, in order NOT to be dependent on first date value being a Sunday. Derived from idea presented by @kguler

```
ticks = Select[DateRange[dset[[1, 1]], dset[[-1, 1]]] , 
    DayMatchQ[#, Wednesday] &] // {#, 
     Rotate["Week " <> ToString@#, \[Pi]/2] & /@ Range@Length@#} & // 
  Transpose;

grid = Select[DateRange[dset[[1, 1]], dset[[-1, 1]]] , 
      DayMatchQ[#, Sunday] &];
```

And here the plot again

```
DateListPlot[dset, Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {DatePlus[dset[[1, 1]], {-1, "Week"}], 0}, 
 GridLines -> {grid, None}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 800, 
 Frame -> False]
```

Points have intentionally not be joined in order to see the irregularity of measurements being taken. (I know, the question assumes 7 data points within 7 days, by the way not stating one on each day. Whereas the data points from  Amundsen-Scott have an irregular number of measurements within 7 days and is only meant for demonstrating how to handle this special case.

[image]

**Update 2**

Weather data from the South Pole:

```
dset = WeatherData["WMO89009", 
   "Temperature", {"Jun. 1, 2014", "Dec. 1, 2014", "Day"}];
```

Using `DayRange` is about 100 times faster to create ticks and grid than using  `Pick` or `Select` in combination with `DateRange`.

```
fnDayDates[d_, dset_] := DayRange[First@First@#, First@Last@#, d]&[dset]

ticks = fnDayDates[Wednesday,dset] // 
        {#,Rotate["Week " <> ToString@#, \[Pi]/2] & /@ Range@Length@#}& //
        Transpose;
```

Here we go:

```
colorAntarctic[ z_ ] := Lighter @ RGBColor[z/2, 1 - z, 1];

DateListPlot[dset, Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[ Bold, 12], 
 AxesOrigin -> {DatePlus[dset[[1, 1]], {-1, "Week"}], 0}, 
 GridLines -> {fnDayDates[Sunday, dset], None}, 
 ColorFunction -> colorAntarctic, Axes -> True, Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,  Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
 ImageSize -> 800, Frame -> False, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["South Pole 90\[Degree]00\[CloseCurlyQuote]S - Jun. 1, \
2014-Dec. 1, 2014", Bold, 14]]
```

[image]

PS: by the way, penguins don't care, hi,hi,hi

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  I need to study these and see how I will fit into the way that I am handling the data and see what works (or variations) of what works best.  At least now I get the idea of what both of these examples are doing.